# Click event not fire for the second element above another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an item like the image below 
[image]

1: click to open detail page 
2: click to switch item status (true/false) and stay on this page 
Element 2 position: absolute and above element 1 
When I click on element 2, click event firing on element 1 and the page redirect to detail page, no event firing for element 2.

Here is my design and code behind:

```
<div class="investment-content_image" ng-click="open(item.id)">
        <div class="closed-overlay-fra">
            <img class="closed-photo" ng-src="{{item.getClosedImage()}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="investment-content-closed" ng-if="!item.open" ng-class="{'active': hovering}" ng-click="open(item.id)">
            <span class="investment-content-closed-text">SOLD OUT</span>
        </div>
        <label class="toggle-switch" ng-if="user.isAdvisor()" ng-click="updateHideInvestment()">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.hide_investor">
            <div class="switch-slider">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>


$scope.open = function (id) {
        if (!$scope.user) {
            return;
        }
        if ($scope.user.isAdmin()) {
            $state.go('admin.showInvestment.overview', {investmentId: id});
        } else if ($scope.user.isInvestor()) {
            $state.go('investor.showInvestment.overview', {investmentId: id});
        } else if ($scope.user.isAdvisor()) {
            $state.go('advisor.showInvestment.overview', {investmentId: id});
        }
    };

$scope.updateHideInvestment = function () {
        let data = {
            id: $scope.item.id,
            hide: $scope.item.hide_investor
        };

        advisorsSvc.updateHideInvestment(data)
            .then((result) => {
                $scope.item.hide_investor = result.hide_investor;
            })
            .catch((err) => { throw err; });
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML and current code that is not working for you. Best if you can add a working code snippet to demonstrate the problem. See ► [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Any code would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated code.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-click` will listen to all click events inside the element and all children elements.

In order to prevent the outer layer from getting the click, you'll need to stop the click from propagating up.

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation(); open(item.id)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide css also? Here simplified version using JQuery

HTML:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#first
{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}

#second
{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:200px;
  margin-top:200px;
  background-color:green;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#first").click(function()
{
    alert("first");
});

$("#second").click(function()
{
    alert("second");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/maximelian/mkgmL83r/

Answer (score 0):

This could be an issue related to Event Bubbling. When an event is triggered on an element, all of its parent elements will fire this event, too. The event is bubbling up parent after parent. You need to stop the propagation of the event on the lowest level.

For this you have to get the generated click event by letting angular pass it to your function.

```
<label class="toggle-switch" ng-if="user.isAdvisor()" ng-click="updateHideInvestment($event)">
```

In the function itself, you have to take the event and stop its propagation.

```
$scope.updateHideInvestment = function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  // Rest of your code here
}
```

This will prevent the event from bubbling up and thus prevent your `open`function from being triggered.